# SQL Counting Using Group By With Multiple Tables and Joins

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count, pivot

I have 3 tables (Schools, Students, Activities) such as simply like these:

**School**

[image: School Table]

**Student**

[image: Student Table]

**Activity**

[image: Activity Table]

I want to get the list for each school the **ALL activities** and number of participants according to the gender in the **2020 ONLY** like this table:

[image: Result]

I did a query like this but it didn't worked as I wanted:

```
SELECT Sc.SchoolName, A.ActivityName, Sc.Year COUNT(Gender)
FROM School Sc
JOIN Student S ON Sc.SchoolID=S.SchoolID
JOIN Activity A ON S.ActivityID=A.ActivityID
GROUP BY Gender
```

How can I fix this? Can you give me solution?

Comment: First, please learn how to use proper `GROUP BY`.  That query won't even execute in almost all of dbms system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    Sc.SchoolName, 
    A.ActivityName, 
    Sc.Year, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 ENd) F,
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 ENd) M
FROM School Sc
JOIN Student S  ON Sc.SchoolID  = S.SchoolID
JOIN Activity A ON S.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
GROUP BY 
    Sc.SchoolName, 
    A.ActivityName, 
    Sc.Year
```

Comment: it shows the table as I wanted with true columns but I need total sums of F's and M's on every rows. your query shows totally 0's

Comment: @Wicaledon: then it means the values you have in column `Gender` of table `Students` are not `'F'` and `'M'`... Check your data.

Comment: I see that I missed something, so sorry dude, it works perfectly ! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT Sc.SchoolName, Sc.Year, A.ActivityName,
      case when Sc.Gender = 'M' then count(1) end as M,
      case when Sc.Gender = 'F' then count(1) end as F
FROM School Sc
JOIN Student S ON Sc.SchoolID=S.SchoolID
JOIN Activity A ON S.ActivityID=A.ActivityID
GROUP BY Sc.SchoolName, Sc.Year, A.ActivityName;
```

Comment: it shows me an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'`. I tried to delete all `as` but now comma is error

Comment: Try now, forgot to mention `end` function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Sc.SchoolName, 
    A.ActivityName, 
    Sc.Year, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.Gender = 'F' THEN StudentID END) as F,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.Gender = 'M' THEN StudentID END) as M
FROM School Sc
INNER JOIN Student S  ON Sc.SchoolID  = S.SchoolID
INNER JOIN Activity A ON S.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
WHERE YEAR LIKE '2020-%'
GROUP BY 
    Sc.SchoolName, 
    A.ActivityName, 
    Sc.Year
```